# Calling Windows executables from Python with Unicode arguments

Tags: python, windows, powershell, unicode, process

When using `os.spawnl()` or `subprocess.run()` functions from Python, Unicode arguments (for example, path values) gets passed as gibberish, and the called executable can't use them.

```
>>> subprocess.run(["ping", "ğü"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
b'Ping request could not find host \xa7\x81. Please check the name and try again.\r\n'
```

```
PS C:\Users\flc> C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE ğü
Ping request could not find host ğü. Please check the name and try again.
```

Strangely, this doesn't happen with `nslookup`:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["nslookup", "ğü"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout`
`*** one.one.one.one can't find ğü: Non-existent domain`
`b'Server:  one.one.one.one\r\nAddress:  1.1.1.1\r\n\r\n'
```

I tested this with `dir` and `echo`, but since they require `shell=True`, I wasn't sure if it was making things seem OK. Hence I picked `ping` and `nslookup`.

Characters `"ğü"` are interpreted as `"\xa7\x81"` by called programs. While on Powershell, `ping` works with Unicode characters. Replacement characters use [cp1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254). It seems like even if I instruct Python to use utf-8, it passes arguments in my local encoding.

What's happening here? How can I safely pass arguments to spawned executables? Is this a problem with Python, or the target executable?

Comment: Add `, encoding = 'cp857'` to the `subprocess.run` parameters?